# Saving form created using Boostrap form builder in mysql database

Tags: javascript, java

i am using bootstrap 2 form builder  and i want to save the form in mysql database in Json format but i don't have a clue were to start. i can create the form but the part that i am struggling with is saving the form for later use.

Comment: instead of down-voting newbies please do help and guide them to ask in right way !

Comment: Do you have a mysql database setup already? Can you post your code?

Comment: @khriskooper yes i do

Comment: You will have to use a server side scripting language to communicate with the MySQL database. Try look at php for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials and answers on how to save form variables to a MySQL database but i will make a very short example here and give you some keywords you can search on to get started.

Here we have som basic HTML markup of a form with a couple of fields using bootstrap classes for styling.

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="POST" class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" class="form-control" />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" class="form-control" />
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This form have a 2 attributes that we want to take a closer look at. The action and method attributes.
The action attribute holds the path to the script that will process the contents of the form once the form is sent. 
The method attribute specifies how to send form-data.

Lets take a look at the process_form.php file

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['message']) ) {
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO messages (firstname,lastname,message) VALUES (:firstname,:lastname,:message)";
            $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array(  ':firstname' => $firstname,
                                ':lastname' => $lastname,
                                ':message' => $message));
            echo "Successfully inserted";

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

First we check to see if there are any POST requests, then we check to see if the POST request if it exists matches with what variables we are after, if it matches we try to establish a connection to a MySQL database using PHP Data Objects (PDO) in a try catch. If the connection gets established we prepare the needed SQL for our purpose and then execute the prepared statement. Last, if the insertion is successfull, we display a message saying so, else we echo out an error starting with *Connection falied:* followed with the PDOExeptions message attribute. As you can see there are a lot of things to learn. If you want to save this data as JSON there are several ways to do that, but one way is when you are inserting into database, instead of doing this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (firstname,lastname,message) VALUES (:firstname,:lastname,:message)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(  ':firstname' => $firstname,
                    ':lastname' => $lastname,
                    ':message' => $message));
echo "Successfully inserted";
```

You do something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (json) VALUES (:json)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(  ':json' => $json));
echo "Successfully inserted";
```

Before this you have to make the json string with PHP. You can do that like this:

```
// First we make a new object.
$jsonObj = new stdClass();
// We assign the different properties to the form variables
$jsonObj->firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$jsonObj->lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$jsonObj->message = $_POST['message'];
// We json encode the object so we can save it to the MySQL database as a string.
$json = json_encode($jsonObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to check this link, This will help you to create a form plus will guide you how to create and save to DB.

*Hope it helps.*

http://tutsme-webdesign.info/bootstrap-form-with-a-script-sending-data-to-a-database/